# Como selecionar múltiplos checkbox a partir de Array ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

No meu HTML tem a seguinte linha:

```
<label class="turnoCurso pretoClaro" id="3"> Vespertino, Noturno  </label>
```

Eu preciso transformar os turnos que são trazidos do banco de dados em um array e para isso eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
var turnoLista = $('#'+id+'.turnoCurso').text().trim();
turnoLista = turnoLista.split(",")
```

E até ai tudo bem, o problema é na hora de deixar os checkbox como checked ele apenas marca o primeiro item e ignora os demais, segue o código que estou utilizando

```
$(turnoLista).each(function(indice, valor){ //

                switch(valor)
                {
                    case "Vespertino":
                        $("#turnoV").prop('checked',true);
                    break;

                    case "Matutino":
                        $("#turnoM").prop('checked',true);
                    break;

                    case "Noturno":
                        $("#turnoN").prop('checked',true);
                    break;

                    case "EAD":
                        $("#turnoE").prop('checked',true);
                    break;
                }

            });
```

Checkbox:

```
<input id="turnoM" type="checkbox" name="turno" value="1"> Matutino
              <input id="turnoV" type="checkbox" name="turno" value="2"> Vespertino
              <input id="turnoN" type="checkbox" name="turno" value="3"> Noturno
              <input id="turnoE" type="checkbox" name="turno" value="4"> EaD
```

O que ocorre é que o código apenas deixa o primeiro chebox checado e caso se coloque um alert dentro do each ele consegue detectar todos os indices do vetor corretamente, alguém saberia como me ajudar ?

Estou utilizando um JS que é incorporado a página através de uma requição Ajax e por isso não consigo debugar o JS.

Comment: Repara que entre "Vespertino" e "Noturno" há um espaço para além da virgula! Devias ter um split mais genérico como `.split(/[, ]/)`. Podes colocar o código do Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solução com forEach nativo do javascript.

**Primeira observação**

Pode ser que você tenha se enganado com a ordem dos valores dentro da função de callback , testei aqui e a assinatura do método forEach ( nativo do javascript ) é:

```
elementos.forEach(function(valor_atual,indice_atual){}
```

Com isso você deve pegar o primeiro argumento ( valor_atual ).

**Segunda observação**

Na hora que você faz o tratamento do valor que está no label não foi completo para poder ser tratado corretamente dentro do forEach.

O valor do texto do label é:

valor_do_label = ' **Vespertino, Noturno**  ';

> Repare que tem 1 espaço antes de Vespetino e outros espaços antes e depois da string após a vírgula.

Com isso deve ser feitos dois tratamentos.

- Na string geral para remover os espaços antes e depois.
- Dentro de cada elemento da lista , para remover os espaços que podem ter ficado entre o separado ( "," ) e cada elemento.

Ficaria assim:

```
elementos = valor_do_label.trim().split(",")
```

E dentro da iteração sobre a lista:

```
elementos.forEach(function(valor,indice){

    valor = valor.trim(); // Aqui removendo os espaços remanescentes que podem quebrar a verificação.

    switch(valor){
        case "Vespetino":
             $("#turnoV").prop('checked',true);
        break;

        case "Matutino":
            $("#turnoM").prop('checked',true);
        break;

        case "Noturno":
            $("#turnoN").prop('checked',true);
        break;

       case "EAD":
           $("#turnoE").prop('checked',true);
       break;
    }
})
```

Comment: O problema realmente estava no TRIM amigo, embora tenha utilizado o trim em var turnoLista = $('#'+id+'.turnoCurso').text().trim() por algum motivo os espaços não foram limpos corretamenta, após trocar o split para turnoLista = turnoLista.trim().split(",") e a variável do switch para valor.trim() passou a funcionar corretamente, o Each que estou utilizando é o do Jquery e o funcionamento realmente é dessa forma (indice,valor) chequei isso antes com um alert, muito obrigado pela força eu nem imaginava.